React Big Calendar Not Displaying Events in Production (MERN Stack)
I'm working on a MERN (MongoDB, Express, React, Node.js) stack application that uses React Big Calendar to display events. Everything works perfectly in my development environment, but in production, events do not show up in the calendar. However, tasks (another feature) work fine in both environments. I am using a DigitalOcean VPS to host the backend and database within Docker containers for production. First image is in production, second is in development.
Not sure what else to do   anymore.


Here is the setup:
server.js
const express = require("express")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path")


dotenv.config()
const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;

const app = express()

app.use(express.json()); // Parses incoming JSON requests
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: (origin, callback) => {
            const allowedOrigins =
                process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
                    ? ["http://localhost:5173", "http://127.0.0.1:5173"]
                    : [
                        "http://www.<sitename>.com",
                        "https://www.<sitename>.com",
                        "http://api.<sitename>.com",
                        "https://api.<sitename>.com",
                    ];
            // Allow no-origin requests for tools like Postman
            if (!origin || allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
                callback(null, true);
            } else {
                callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
            }
        },
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
        allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
        credentials: true, // Allow credentials if needed
    })
);

const eventsRoutes = require("./routes/events");
app.use("/api/events", eventsRoutes);

const tasksRoutes = require("./routes/tasks");
app.use("/api/tasks", tasksRoutes);


// Connect to MongoDB and start backend server
mongoose
    .connect(MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
    .catch((error) => console.error("MongoDB connection error:", error));

// Start server
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`));

events.js
const express = require("express")
const Event = require("../models/Event")

const router = express.Router()

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("GET /api/events received")
    try {
        const events = await Event.find()
        console.log("Fetched events:", events); // Log the fetched events
        res.json(events)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching events:", error)
        res.status(500).json({message: "Server error"})
    }
})

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const newEvent = new Event(req.body)
        const savedEvent = await newEvent.save()
        res.status(201).json(savedEvent)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error saving event:", error)
        res.status(500).json({message: "Failed to save event"})
    }
})

router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const updatedEvent = await Event.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {new: true})
        res.json(updatedEvent)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error updating event:", error)
        res.status(500).json({message: "Failed to update event"})
    }
})

router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Event.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
        res.status(204).send()
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error deleting event:", error)
        res.status(500).json({message: "Failed to delete event"})
    }
})

module.exports = router

Event.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    start: {type: Date, required: true},
    end: {type: Date, required: true},
    allDay: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    description: {type: String},
    location: {type: String},
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Event", eventSchema)

For comparison, here is tasks.js
const express = require("express")
const Task = require("../models/Task")

const router = express.Router()

// Get all tasks
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("GET /api/tasks received");
    try {
        const tasks = await Task.find();
        res.json(tasks);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching tasks:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Server Error" });
    }
});

// Add a new task
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const newTask = new Task(req.body)
    const savedTask = await newTask.save()
    res.status(201).json(savedTask)
})

// Update a task
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const updatedTask = await Task.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, { new: true });
        res.json(updatedTask);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error updating task:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to update task" });
    }
});

// Delete a task
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    await Task.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    res.status(204).send()
})

module.exports = router

Task.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    completed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Task", taskSchema)

And fetchTasks in the TodoList component
// Base URL for API calls
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL:
    import.meta.env.MODE === "development" ? "/api" : import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
});

// Fetch tasks on component load
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTasks = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await api.get("/tasks") // Fetch tasks from backend
        console.log("Fetched tasks:", data)

        // Separate tasks into pending and completed
        const pending = data.filter((task) => !task.completed)
        const completed = data.filter((task) => task.completed)
        setPendingTasks(pending)
        setCompletedTasks(completed)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching tasks:", error.response || error.message)
      }
    }

    fetchTasks()
}, []) // Runs only once on mount

Edit: Here is the CalendarPanel component
const locales = {
    "en-US": enUS
}

const localizer = dateFnsLocalizer({
    format,
    parse,
    startOfWeek,
    getDay,
    locales,
});

const CalendarPanel = () => {
    const [events, setEvents] = useState([])

    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL:
            import.meta.env.MODE === "development" ? "/api" : import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchEvents = async () => {
            try {
                const { data } = await api.get("/events") // Fetch events from backend
                console.log("Fetched events:", data)

                // Ensure start and end are converted to Date objects
                const formattedEvents = data.map(event => ({
                    ...event,
                    start: new Date(event.start),
                    end: new Date(event.end),
                }));

                setEvents(formattedEvents)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching events:", error.response || error.message)
            }
        }

        fetchEvents()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="calendar-panel">
            <h2 className="drag-handle">Calendar</h2>
            <Calendar
                localizer={localizer}
                events={events}
                startAccessor="start"
                endAccessor="end"
                className="calendar"
                views={["month", "week", "day", "agenda"]} // Enable different views
                defaultView="month" // Set default view
                style={{ height: "500px" }} // Inline styles for height
                onSelectEvent={(event) =>
                    window.confirm("Do you want to delete this event?") &&
                    handleDeleteEvent(event._id)
                } // Click to delete event
            />
        </div>
    )
}

This is package.json from the frontend
{
  "name": "planner",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.5",
    "@mui/material": "^6.1.8",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "date-fns": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-big-calendar": "^1.15.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-grid-layout": "^1.5.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.13.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.3",
    "eslint": "^9.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.14",
    "globals": "^15.11.0",
    "sass-embedded": "^1.81.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.10",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^4.3.0"
  }
}


Adding that 2 instances of Events do exist in the production database. Yet fetch in production returns 404 and html content.

Where is the code to get the events. I imagine it is similar to getTasks()?

@jQueeny yes, thank you for catching that. I had forgotten to include the fetchTasks. Edited to show it now along with the calendar panel component

If the fetchEvents request returns a 404 it means the endpoint was not found. Inside the fetchEvents function do a console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL) to make sure it is what you expect it to be. When you look in the network tab of your browser dev tools what endpoint does it say for the fetchEvents request?

@jQueeny I've added that log you gave to both fetchTasks() and fetchEvents() just to compare the two. They both return the same https://api..com/api. The error from the fetchEvents() returns an html:
Error fetching events:
Object { data: '\n\n\n\nError\n\n\nNot Found\n\n\n', status: 404, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }

fetchTasks() returns a json object as it should, but the fetchEvents() returns that html error

Post your front-end package.json file.

@jQueeny Edited to include package.json

Can you check if other route names are affected. So try changing the fetch to await api.get("/advents") and on the server app.use("/api/advents", eventsRoutes); just for a sanity check.

@jQueeny changed the fetch and server code to use advents instead, even inserted into database:

db.advents.insert({ "title": "Meet with pen salesman", "start": new Date("2024-12-25T10:00:00Z"), "end": new Date("2024-12-25T12:00:00Z"), "allDay": false, "description": "Discuss sales tactics", "location": "Chicago" })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

It's still giving same error, just showing /api/advents now instead of /api/events

I've never used DigitalOcean to host but are you sure the server.js isn't being cached or something? If you add app.use((req, res, next) => console.log('Request logged at: ', Date.now()); next();}); above your other routes it should log the time for every request made to your backend. If it doesn't log anything then the server.js isn't being served.

It looks like either your server.js is not deployed to your prod environment correctly, or the router for the events endpoints is not registered correctly. You can try to temporarily add the routes for events and tasks to a single router object in e.g. events-and-tasks.js, prefixing endpoints accordingly (you can also change the base path temporarily to e.g. api2 so you can make sure that the update got deployed successfully):
events-and-tasks.js:
const express = require("express")
// ...

const router = express.Router()

router.get("/events", async (req, res) => {
  // ...
})

router.get("/tasks", async (req, res) => {
  // ...
})

module.exports = router

server.js
const routes = require("./routes/events-and-tasks");
app.use("/api2", routes);

If /api2/events and /api2/tasks both work, there is something going on with how the two separate routers are added. I would check a few more things in this case:

If you add the tasks router first and the events router second, does that fix the events endpoint and break the tasks endpoint?
Is there any difference in the backend project setup between the dev and prod environments? (It would be helpful if you described your deployment workflow.)
Clear your browser cache and try again, just in case.

